# How to model class in order to serialize Dart Object (Map<String, List>) into JSON in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization

I have a Map<Datetime, List> in Dart that stores events needed to fill up a calendar in my Flutter app:

```
    final Map<DateTime, List> _events = {
    DateTime(2020, 7, 7): [
      {'name': 'Event A', 'isDone': true},
    ],
    DateTime(2020, 7, 11): [
      {'name': 'Event A', 'isDone': true}
    ],
    DateTime(2020, 7, 9): [
      {'name': 'Event A', 'isDone': true},
      {'name': 'Event B', 'isDone': true},
    ],
    DateTime(2020, 7, 10): [
      {'name': 'Event A', 'isDone': true},
      {'name': 'Event B', 'isDone': true},
    ],
    DateTime(2020, 7, 13): [
      {'name': 'Event A', 'isDone': true},
      {'name': 'Event B', 'isDone': true},
      {'name': 'Event C', 'isDone': false},
    ],
    DateTime(2020, 7, 25): [
      {'name': 'Event A', 'isDone': true},
      {'name': 'Event B', 'isDone': true},
      {'name': 'Event C', 'isDone': false},
    ],
    DateTime(2020, 7, 6): [
      {'name': 'Event A', 'isDone': false},
    ],
  };
```

I want to convert this into JSON but I'm not entirely sure how to model the class. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to convert this to a JSON you can use the `jsonEncode` function and use the `toEncodable` named parameter to allow your object to be encoded. I made an example here that just cast the keys of your `Map` to a `String` so that it can be encoded.

```dart
jsonEncode(
  _events,
  toEncodable: (input) {
    return _events.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key.toString(), value);
    });
  }
);
```

When you want to decode this back to your `Map<DateTime, List>` you can just do the reverse.

```dart
var objectTemp = jsonDecode(
  json,
);
var output = objectTemp.map((key, value) {
  return MapEntry(DateTime.parse(key), value);
})
```

Comment: Appreciate it. May you also please clarify a few things? What is 'decoded'? I tried running the code but I got 

'type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, List<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'String''

Comment: Oh sorry I'll fix that. It should be `objectTemp`.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to clarify I'm turning the events into JSON then storing them into a database. When I'm retrieving it and trying to decode I'm getting an error when trying to decode 

'Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, List<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: This implies that when you are doing retrieval it's already decoded. JSON is a `String` yet you already have a `Map`. Are you already decoding it at some point?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I'm using Hive to retrieve the JSON from the box so maybe it already decodes then.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Hive`, but it is almost definitely already decoded, so just don't use the decoding I proposed.

Comment: Yea you're right. Thank you so much. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class for `Event` and store the event data in it (name, isDone and date). Then you put them in a `List<Event>`. You can search on this list for a spesific date and get the according events if any. Then you can make that data class [serializable](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes).